# Error creating R 3.0.1 package "Vignette product ‘Sample.tex’ does not have a known filename extension (‘NA’)"

Tags: r, package, vignette

I'm trying to build my own custom R package under R 3.0.1.  This package builds fine in previous versions of R.  It works successfully except I'm getting an error creating the vignette.

I have a Sample.Rnw in my inst/doc directory that includes some other .tex files in that directory.

I'm getting the following error when I try to build the package.  I can't find any reference to what this means or why there is even a Sample.tex file getting created.

```
Vignette product ‘Sample.tex’ does not have a known filename extension (‘NA’)
```

Any advice on how to figure out what this error means would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probable do not have latex installed. Try to add `--no-manual` and `--no-build-vignettes`. See `R CMD build --help` for details